# How to login with mobile number in parse but user should get verification code by text or call on that number?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, parse-platform

I want to login in my app with mobile number and I have used Parse at background.There are 2 methods for getting verification code
1.By call
2.By text on that mobile number.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to integrate 3rd party apis for sms/telephonic verifications.

Refer to the following services:-

1. http://www.numberguru.com/developer
2. http://www.openmarket.com/
3. http://www.textanywhere.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "Digit By Twitter " it's very powerful api.

here is the link for it and it's easy to integrate.

https://get.digits.com